# Subgroups of $S_n$ that can send any subset of $[n]$ to any equally sized subset of $[n]$

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

This is a repost of a question I was trying to solve yesterday that got deleted. The question asked for a characterization of the subgroups $G$ of $S_n$ which when endowed with their natural action on $2^{[n]}$ satisfy that if $M$ and $N$ are equal-sized subsets of $[n]$ then there is a permutation $\varphi$ in $G$ so that $\varphi(M)=N$.

So you don't ask  what I have tried later:

The group is clearly primitive. If $n!/|G|=k$ The order of the stabilizer of a subset $S$ of size $m$ is $\frac{(n-m)!(m)!}{k}$ (This is because we want the same orbits as when $S_n$ is acting an we use the orbit-stabilizer theorem)

Comment: The original OP conjectured the subgroup had to be $S_n$ or $A_n$

Comment: The paper http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01113919#page-1 contains a classification of $k$-homogeneous bu not $k$-transitive groups with $n \ge 2k$. In particular, for $k \ge 5$ and $n \ge 2k$, all $k$-homogenoeus groups are $k$-transitive.

Comment: @DerekHolt that's interesting. Are there any examples of groups that are not $A_n$ or $S_n$ that satisfy the conditions of the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an old result of Jordan that a transitive subgroup of $S_n$ that contains an element of prime order $p$ with $n/2 < p < n-2$ is equal to $A_n$ or $S_n$. This applies to groups satisfying your hypothesis provided that there exists such a prime, which is true for $n \ge 8$.